# Different host and routes in Symfony witho JMS i18n

Tags: php, symfony, localization, internationalization

I want different host and different routes in my multicountry web with Symfony 3. I used the JMS i18n routing for this.
My config YML file:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: es_ES
    locales: [es_ES, fr_FR, en_GB]
    strategy: custom
    hosts:
        es_ES: www.aaa.local
        fr_FR: www.aaa-fr.local
        en_GB: www.aaa-uk.local
    redirect_to_host: true
```

With this, I can use different host correctly, but I don't know how I can "translate" the routes, f.ex: `/contacto` `/contact` and `/contact`.

I want load differents `routing.yml` depends on the locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the JMSI18nRoutingBundle your routes are being Translated automatically based on your `route_name` using the `routes` domain (Symfony Translation Component).
So, assumed your `route_name` is contact, just create a Translations like this:

```
id/source: contact
domain: routes
locale: en
translation/target: /contact

id/source: contact
domain: routes
locale: es
translation/target: /contacto
```

Now your routes using the Symfony `router` (which is wrapped by the one from the bundle) will return automatically the translated route from the current locale.
If you want to translate it to a specific locale, just add the route parameter `_locale` like this:

```
{{ path("contact", {"_locale": "es"}) }}
```

or

```
$this->get('router')->generate('contact', array('_locale' => 'es'));
```

Comment: I have to add this code in my `messages.es_Es.yml`? I actualy using .po/.mo translation files

Comment: it's not "code", not a specific format (not yml). But you can just use your .po/.mo translation files for this.

Comment: Ok, I generate a new translation file: routes.es_ES.po (and .mo) with this:

    `msgid "contact"`
    `msgstr "contacto"`

But if I go to /contacto the route is not matching. Can you please tell me how and where can translate this "part" of the route? Thankyou!

Comment: msgstr should be "/contacto".. This will be the actual path.. (you can even use parameters like "/contacto/{user}/anything")